# Definition of fixed point free relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, relations

If we have such relation that for $\forall x$ $f(x)\ne x$ , how is it called in one word? I can come up with only "graph of this function is not a straight line:)"
Thank you

Comment: Your description is not correct. There are plenty of graphs which are not straight lines but satisfy this. This property is called fixed-point free.

Comment: What is not correct about my description?

Comment: @SergFillipenko the graph of the line $y=x+1$. Is a straight line, but also has no fixed points.

Comment: Further to what @rschwieb said, just because the graph is not a straight line, the function can still have fixed-points.

Comment: Also please use a better title @SergFillipenko

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft "There are plenty of graphs which are not straight lines but satisfy this", probably you meant "There are plenty of graphs which are straight lines but do not satisfy this"

Comment: Essentially "graph of this function is not a straight line" (call this statement $P$) has nothing to do with the condition $\forall x\; f(x)\neq x$ (call this statement $Q$). On the one hand $f(x)=x^2$ satisfies $P$ (the graph is not a straight line) but fails $Q$ ($0^2=0$).  So $P$ is not a sufficient condition. On the other hand $f(x)=x+1$ fails $P$ (the graph is a straight line) but satisfies $Q$ ($\forall x\;(x+1\neq x)$). So your statement has nothing to do with your relation.

Comment: $f$ is "fixed-point-free", as you observe. If $f$ is a bijection of some set (a permutation) then it's called a *derangement*.